# Two out of three rigs having hard freezes

Tags: mining

I'm a newbee.. Please pardon if I've missed any critical detail in this question.

I have three ASUS Z270 AR motherboards and 21 Asus dual RX 580 GPUs. Out of these, one rig with 7 GPUs work really well. I'm having problems with the other two. Whenever I connect more than one GPU to any of the other two motherboards, only one card hashes while the other does 0 hashing and in a minute, the whole Windows 10 desktop freezes and i have to reboot. I even tried with ETHOS it has the same issue.

Ive done the bios mods on the motherboard for the pch gen2. The computer works just fine and shows all the 7 cards in the device manager correctly. Only when i start the claymore dual miner, that's when it crashes in a minute.

When i try to connect one single GPU - one by one on every PCI-E slot, all the slots works just fine independently they hash at 27mhs.

When i try to connect one GPU at a time to its appropriate PCI-E slot, every GPU hashes just fine at 24 to 27 mhs.

I'm using a 450W gold power supply for each rig along with two HP DPS1200 power supplies.

Any guidance you could provide on how to fix/troubleshoot would be of great help.

Comment: You might try at reddit.com/r/EtherMining. Also 450W seems too low for a GPU.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll post at reddit as well. The 450w is just for the mother board and the riser cards. The GPUs are driven by the DPS 1200 power supply.